# Selenium how check an element loads correctly more than once and log results

Tags: selenium, frameworks

I am trying to test a website with selenium using robot framework, I am going backwards and forwards between 2 pages and checking that the second one (problem page is loaded each time)and keeping a count of the results, I'm using the following code

```
def check_contents_page_loads(self, passed, failed, attempts, counter):
    self.driver.get(self.mm + '/config/views')
    attempts = int(attempts)
    passed = int(passed)
    failed = int(failed)
    counter = int(counter)
    return_passed = str(passed)
    return_counter = str(counter)

try:
    while attempts > 0:
    attempts -= 1
    counter += 1
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav-config").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav-content").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    test = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("resource-navigator").is_displayed()
    print(test)
    if test == "True":
        passed += 1
    else:
        failed += 1

except Exception, ex:
    logging.exception('dasse %s , %s' % (ex, Exception))
    return False

return return_passed, return_counter
```

When the page is present this works but if the page is not I get the following error message

Cannot assign return values: Expected list-like object, got bool instead.

From robot I am sending the following values

```
${passed} Set Variable 0
${failed} Set Variable 0
${attempts} Set Variable 20
${counter} Set Variable 0
${return_passed} ${return_counter} Check Contents Page Loads ${passed} ${failed} ${attempts} ${counter}
Should be Equal ${return_passed} ${return_counter}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, you're returning a bool of false.  You need to correct that.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I deal with the exception, I want the script to continue running as the exception is a warning caused by the page not loading, in this situation I want to increase the failed variable and continue in the while loop until the number of attempts is 0